# Auto Post from my one WP to another WP

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I automatically create a post to another Wordpress site that I own with the same content that I used on the post on my Main Wordpress site.

e.g; whenever I post something on ABC.COM it should automatically be posted on the DEF.COM website as well, exact same content along with the same title.

Let me know if anything like that exist in Wordpress plugins or anything that can make this possible.

Thanks

Comment: You can do it by WPMU

Comment: @jothikannan Can you please give me the exact name of the plugin or URL? Thanks

Comment: surely you can get it by my idea, i have done it before a month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must enable the wordpress Network in order to do it, kindly have look at here [WPMU](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), thereafter you can share the post via another wordpress website in your network. using this [ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use a RSS Widget. Try this link : http://wordpress.org/plugins/kb-advanced-rss-widget/

You can also try : http://www.codeigniter.in/blog/post/how-to-get-posts-from-a-wordpress-site-to-other-sites-hosted-in-same-server

Comment: I want it to fully show the posts as it was created from the admin panel of WP, i don't want it to show as on widgets/sidebar etc, I want it to be post as a create new post, just the normal way we make a post on a website but automatically.

Comment: Try http://www.codeigniter.in/blog/post/how-to-get-posts-from-a-wordpress-site-to-other-sites-hosted-in-same-server